# TeamCity - Error - Found a TeamCity internal database when no system directory or an empty system directory is expected

Tags: teamcity

Our TeamCiity server was restarted the other day and it is coming up with no projects listed.  There should be a total of 3.  I did not configure this machine and any help is appreciated.

output of our teamcity-server log:

```
[2014-02-08 12:59:56,263]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - =========================================================== 
[2014-02-08 12:59:56,263]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Starting TeamCity server 
[2014-02-08 12:59:56,919]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - TeamCity version: 8.0.5 (build 27692), data format version 628 
[2014-02-08 12:59:56,919]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - OS: Windows Server 2008, JRE: 1.7.0_21-b11 
[2014-02-08 12:59:56,919]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Servlet real path: C:\Program Files\TeamCity\bin\..\webapps\ROOT\ 
[2014-02-08 12:59:56,919]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Current stage: Looking for the TeamCity Data Directory 
[2014-02-08 12:59:56,919]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - TeamCity Data Directory path is determined using the environment variable TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH 
[2014-02-08 12:59:56,919]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Data Directory "C:\sandbox\Build Configuration" exists 
[2014-02-08 12:59:57,169]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - The main configuration file "C:\sandbox\Build Configuration\config\main-config.xml" doesn't exist 
[2014-02-08 12:59:57,169]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - The database properties file "C:\sandbox\Build Configuration\config\database.properties" doesn't exist 
[2014-02-08 12:59:57,169]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - The internal database data file "C:\sandbox\Build Configuration\system\buildserver.data" exists 
[2014-02-08 12:59:57,169]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Startup confirmation is required. Open TeamCity web page in the browser. 
[2014-02-08 12:59:57,169]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Current stage: Confirming TeamCity first start 
[2014-02-10 13:36:55,062]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Current stage: Initializing Data Directory 
[2014-02-10 13:36:55,265]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Current stage: Creating a new database 
[2014-02-10 13:36:55,265]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Creating a new internal (HSQL) database 
[2014-02-10 13:37:13,593]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Connected to the database successfully 
[2014-02-10 13:37:13,624]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Using schema: PUBLIC 
[2014-02-10 13:37:13,655]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Schema contains 120 tables. 
[2014-02-10 13:37:13,671]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Database version is 628 
[2014-02-10 13:37:13,671]  ERROR -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Found a TeamCity internal database when no system directory or an empty system directory is expected 
[2014-02-10 13:37:13,671]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Current stage: TeamCity server startup error 
[2014-02-10 15:20:01,106]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Server shutdown has been requested 
[2014-02-10 15:20:01,106]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Current stage: The system is shutting down 
[2014-02-10 15:20:01,106]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Stopping the main application 
[2014-02-10 15:20:01,107]   INFO - ide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager - Performing shutdown on HSQL database... 
[2014-02-10 15:20:04,184]   INFO - ide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager - HSQL database shutdown performed successfully. 
[2014-02-10 15:20:04,185]   INFO -   jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - Unregsitered 2 drivers successfully. 
[2014-02-10 15:20:04,185]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Server shutdown complete 
[2014-02-10 15:21:46,015]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP -
```